# SQL query to increment value based on multiple groupby

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have a requirement where i have to perform below task

Col5 is basically using col4 and col3

i can do the formatting for col5 but confused as in how to increment value when it's 1 or 0

[image]

Comment: perfectly fine if we can use parition by to get this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sum()` window function:

```
select *,
  cast(sum(col4) over (partition by col1 order by col3) as varchar) +
  '/' +
  cast(col3 as varchar) col5
from tablename
```

or if the order is defined by `date`:

```
select *,
  cast(sum(col4) over (partition by col1 order by col2) as varchar) +
  '/' +
  cast(col3 as varchar) col5
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68f86dae30b900c09e9aecf804fca573).
Results:

```
> col1 | col2       | col3 | col4 | col5
> :--- | :--------- | ---: | ---: | :---
> abc  | 2019-03-20 |    1 |    1 | 1/1 
> abc  | 2019-03-21 |    2 |    0 | 1/2 
> abc  | 2019-03-22 |    3 |    1 | 2/3 
> def  | 2019-03-22 |    1 |    0 | 0/1 
> def  | 2019-03-23 |    2 |    1 | 1/2 
> def  | 2019-03-24 |    3 |    0 | 1/3
```

Comment: Hi
that logic worked but they changed the requirement by adding another column which has multiple records with respect to the date column.
As a result, the sum at the end is printed incorrectly. Just edited my image with the updated data

Comment: This is a different requirement and you should post a new question about it where you explain how this new column will be derived because it is not as clear as the previous one.